# Merge two JSON with a matching ID in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I got two JSON that are structured like this. First one comes from an API:

```
[
  {
   "course_code":"Basic 101 - 0913",
   "name":"Basic 101",
   "start_at":"2013-09-16T00:00:00+02:00",
   "end_at":"2013-10-13T23:55:00+02:00",
   "workflow_state":"available"
  },
  {"course_code":"Medium 201 - 0913",
   "name":"Medium 201",
   "start_at":"2013-08-06T16:55:25+02:00",
   "end_at":null,
   "workflow_state":"available"
  }
]
```

The second one is a JSON export from my database:

```
[
  {
   "id":1,
   "course_id":"Basic 101",
   "name":"Basic Level",
   "description":"blablabla",
   "discipline_id":"1",
   "duration":"28",
   "created_at":null,
   "updated_at":null
  },
  {
   "id":2,
   "course_id":"Medium 201",
   "name":"Medium Level",
   "description":"blablabla",
   "discipline_id":"1",
   "duration":"28",
   "created_at":null,
   "updated_at":null
  }
]
```

I would like to merge these two JSON into one, with matched `:name` in the first JSON and `:course_id` in the second one.

If you know good tutorials on using JSON in Rails, I'm really interested.

Comment: thanks @YevgeniyAnfilofyev I'll take care of that next time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a quick answer, to let you know where to go. Assuming first json is in `json1` and second is in `json2` variables, this code:

```
require 'json'

arr1 = JSON.parse(json1)
arr2 = JSON.parse(json2)
mrg = []
arr1.each do |el1|
  arr2.each do |el2|
    if el2['course_id'] == el1['name']
      mrg.push(el1.merge(el2))
    end
  end
end

p mrg
```

Will print:

```
[
  {
   "course_code"=>"Basic 101 - 0913",
   "name"=>"Basic Level", 
   "start_at"=>"2013-09-16T00:00:00+02:00", 
   "end_at"=>"2013-10-13T23:55:00+02:00", 
   "workflow_state"=>"available", 
   "id"=>1, 
   "course_id"=>"Basic 101", 
   "description"=>"blablabla", 
   "discipline_id"=>"1", 
   "duration"=>"28", 
   "created_at"=>nil, 
   "updated_at"=>nil
  },
  {
   "course_code"=>"Medium 201 - 0913", 
   "name"=>"Medium Level", 
   "start_at"=>"2013-08-06T16:55:25+02:00", 
   "end_at"=>nil, 
   "workflow_state"=>"available", 
   "id"=>2, 
   "course_id"=>"Medium 201", 
   "description"=>"blablabla", 
   "discipline_id"=>"1", 
   "duration"=>"28", 
   "created_at"=>nil, 
   "updated_at"=>nil
  }
]
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you, it's indeed way more beautiful than my code :)

Answer (score 5):

This isn't really a JSON issue.

When parsing JSON data it returns arrays and hashes.

One way of merging it in *this* case would be to loop through the data and check for the parameters you want/need to match. Once you find a match you can either manually create a new Hash with the needed data or you could use

```
hash1.merge(hash2)
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge

which would return a hash consisting of both Hashes - attributes with the same name would be overwritten in the first hash.